# Angular2 router config, prefix pathMatch does not work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

From what I understand from Angular2 router documentation, the routes config default pathMatch strategy is "prefix", 
"prefix" pathMatch strategy means the the app router only needs to look on the start of the url and match it with the proper route.

Reference: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html#!#matching-strategy

That been said, with the below configurations I would assume that this route should load `ExampleComponent` if I navigate to `/abcdefg`.

One problem that **this is not working**, am not sure what is wrong and i cant find much information about this on google or in `@angular/router` source code.

Thank you for your help.

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix', canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: [
    { path:'abc', pathMatch: 'prefix', component: ExampleComponent},
    { path: '', component: HomepageComponent }
  ]},
 ];


 export const ROUTING = RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: false });
```

**Update #1, Trying *Günter Zöchbauer* suggestion.**

new router configurations are:

now `/abc/defg` works but not `/abcdefg`

```
{ path:'abc', pathMatch: 'prefix',
  children: [
    { path:'**', component:ExampleComponent},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, someone was asking me how i solved this issue,

first i added a new route as a fallback to all other routes, something like this:

```
{path: ':url', loadChildren: './fallback/fallback.module#FallbackModule'}
```

then inside fallbackComponent we decide what module to load based on the url on router navigation end event.

in my case, if the url was /@somestring, i wanted to load the profileComponent and call some APIs

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        this.parseUrl(this.router.url);
      });
  }

  parseUrl(url: string) {
    let data = {};
    let parts: string[] = url.split('/');
    parts = parts.filter((item) => !!item);
    if (parts[0] && parts[0].indexOf('@') === 0) {
      data['component'] = 'profile';
      data['username'] = parts[0].replace('@', '');
    }
    this.viewData = data;
  }
```

and in the template:

```
<template [ngIf]="viewData && viewData['component'] == 'profile'">
  <user-profile
    [title] = "viewData['view']"
    [username] = "viewData['username']"
  ></user-profile>
</template>
```

also worth to mention that we also had to override DefaultUrlSerializer.serialize to disable auto encoding for special characters (@) in urls.

Answer (score 5):

That would work if your `path: 'abc'` route had a child route with `path: 'defg'` or `path: '**'` or `path: 'de'` and the child route had a route with `path: 'fg'`.

`pathMatch: 'full'` means, that the whole URL path needs to match and is consumed by the route matching algorithm.

`pathMatch: 'prefix'` means, the first route where the path matches the start of the URL is choosen, but then the route matching algorithm is continuing searching for matching child routes where the rest of the URL matches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried your suggestion, now `abc/de` works, but not `abcde`, i'll update the question now to show you the new configurations.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain that part properly. That is only supposed to work with `abc/de` but not with `abcde`. In praxis `pathMatch` is only to decide if the route matching algorithm should continue searching with an empty path on child routes when `''` already matched on the parent route. This is a special case because it's hard to now if "nothing" should be consumed when it matches or not. I don't know of other use cases for `pathMatch`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're saying :

```
{ path: '', component: MainLayoutComponent, pathMatch: 'prefix'
```

which basically saying :

Find any url that starts with nothing ('') and simply enough,  all the urls always start with nothing.

Consider this   url   `/google`

Or       this   url

if you run a Regex and say does these urls match to ''?, yes the do.

Unless you say the starting `(^)` and ending `($)` bit should match too, which in that case, starting will match for both of them , but ending will only match to the empty url.

That's what they've created the `full` prefix , as to say , the url should exactly match .